# Maven: put dependent jar to different war folder instead of war/web-inf/lib

Tags: web-services, maven-2, maven, apache-axis

Currently I'm trying to make maven build task for axis2-based project.
In my `pom.xml` i have defined dependency jar file. and i want that when war is building, the jar will be moved to another directory: not in `war/web-inf/lib` but to `war/web-inf/servicejars`

I looked through similar questions on stackoverflow but they didn't helped.

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>MyService</artifactId>
            <!-- didnt work for me -->
            <!--<properties>-->
                <!--<war.target.path>servicejars</war.target.path>-->
            <!--</properties>-->
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- etc ... -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>Axis2</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <!--<plugin> Didn't worked too-->
                <!--<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
                <!--<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>-->
                <!--<version>2.1</version>-->
                <!--<executions>-->
                    <!--<execution>-->
                        <!--<id>copydep</id>-->
                        <!--<phase>prepare-package</phase>-->
                        <!--<goals>-->
                            <!--<goal>copy-dependencies</goal>-->
                        <!--</goals>-->
                        <!--<inherited>false</inherited>-->
                        <!--<configuration>-->
                            <!--<includeArtifactIds>MyService</includeArtifactIds>-->
                            <!--<outputDirectory>$project.build.directory/${project.build.finalName}/web-inf/servicejars</outputDirectory>-->
                        <!--</configuration>-->
                    <!--</execution>-->
                <!--</executions>-->
            <!--</plugin>-->
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `i want that when war is building, the jar will be moved to another directory: not in war/web-inf/lib but to war/web-inf/servicejars` is there a reason for this? why don't you let maven handle dependencies?

Comment: actually i need to deploy this as axis2 service. if it can be done by some plugin - it would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).  You can do this using the [assembly descriptor file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/using-components.html) and the `dir` format.  Probably not quite the example your looking for but a good place to start is example they provide with the plugin documentation: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/including-and-excluding-artifacts.html

And here's a good link to the how the assembly descriptor model looks:  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html